# Antenna coupling via capacitor

Tags: antenna, receiver

Assume we have following section of a more or less elementary receiver
circuit consisting of an resonant circuit L1 & C2 and an antenna coupled
via capacitor C2 to the resonant circuit (source: http://makearadio.com/misc-stuff/regennotes.php):

[image]

Well, and my question is simply what is the usage of this coupling
capacitor C1 here?

Of course in general if we are going to connect two separate parts of a circuit over a coupling capacitor, one of it's main jobs there is to prevent the DC from passing through it.

The question is if in this receiver circuit above the only usage of C1 is really just to kill DC or does it fulfill more deeper tasks here, like effects on the bandwidth of the receiver etc.?

Comment: Please link to where you saw this circuit. As it stands, there is no apparent use for the capacitor except in very exceptional situations hence, background details are required.

Comment: @Andyaka: I found it here: http://makearadio.com/misc-stuff/regennotes.php There is at all no explanantion on 'what this coupling capacitor does there.' It's just depicted there, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *@Andyaka: I found it here: [makearadio.com/misc-stuff/regennotes.php](http://makearadio.com/misc-stuff/regennotes.php)
> There is at all no explanation on 'what this coupling capacitor does
> there.' It's just depicted there, that's it.*

According to the article you linked (where you saw the design or read about it), there is this paragraph about regenerative receiver radios: -

[image]

The article also goes on to show other variants with your circuit being on the left: -

[image]

And, of course the main reason for tuning at the front-end of the radio is because the type of receiver is **regenerative** and, this is a type of radio where the only provision for tuning **is** at the front-end (unlike superhet receivers).

So, both series and parallel capacitors are adjusted to tune in a station over a broad span of possible channels. This ensures that you can obtain the right amount of Q-factor no-matter which station you tune into. The right amount of Q-factor determines the bandwidth of what is received and thus the reproduced audio is kept at a fairly constant bandwidth. It's a bit of a fiddly way of doing things i.e. it is labour intensive but, it can work.

Of course, with superhet receivers, the tuning bandwidth is fixed by the I.F. stage and no adjustments are needed except to move the local oscillator to select the desired station. So, this is basically a problem of regenerative receivers because, at one end of the tuning dial the Q-factor is too shallow and you pick-up too much background interference whilst, at the other end of the tuning dial, the Q-factor is much higher and the audio sounds dull.

In another answer this is stated: *It's used in order not to bring DC voltage to the antenna* and that is clearly missing the point. That is why I asked you to explain the source of your circuit and why I said that the capacitor is used *except in very exceptional situations* and clearly, a regenerative receiver is one of them.

---

**A bit more background information**

The regenerative receiver was a big leap from using a crystal set but, tuning had to remain at the antenna. For 1 MHz reception, the ideal monopole length is 75 metres and, that ain't happening in all but the most dedicated set-ups. However, for much shorter antennas, the net capacitance (a feature of short antennas) requires that you only needed a single coil to tune in to a station. So, early crystal sets used this "benefit" and got quite good selectivity across a tunable band.

However, it produces poor quality due to changes in Q-factor as you crossed from one end of the band to the other. Hence the series and parallel tuning capacitor arrangement offered both selectivity and Q-factor compensation.

Comment: a stupid question: when you a talking about 'the Q factor' do always mean the Q factor of the resonant LC 'tuning' circuit or that one of the antenna itself (which of course can be considered as a resonant circuit as well)?

Comment: The antenna won't be "resonant"; only a quarter-wave or half-wave antenna operating at the "right" frequency can be considered to be resonant. There is electrical resonance of course but that is formed by the series capacitor, parallel capacitor and inductor @katalaveino

Comment: @katalaveino I see that you may need to [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand what you should do when you have at least one satisfactory answer to a question. "Playing the game" ensures better attention on newer questions you raise.

Comment: I have looked the answers carefully through and I quite not
sure if I understand the precise reason what the 
job of this cacitor C1 at all is.

Comment: What I understand: Roughly, of course at the end of the day 
the job of C_1 and C_2 is to tune the receiver. The role 
of C_2 is quite easy: it adapts the circuit to the
desired resonance frequence which we would like to extract.  

But my question was focused on the role of C_1. Although
all answers refer to tuning here I'm a bit sceptical
about them (that issue motivated me also to post 
the question about tuning and matching (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/594476/difference-between-tuning-and-matching-for-transmitter-receiver-circuits)

Comment: The reason why I still haven't accepted one of them 
is that I think that they contain only vague hints, but
not the precise reason what the duty of this capacitor C_1
there finally is.

 I would like to try to explain rigorously how 
I understood the task of this coupling capacitor C_1 here.
Could you please look through if it's correct now?

Comment: Firstly, I conjecture that based on logic in some answers
I got in the linked question in that case the job of C_1 
is exactly a matching job. Why I think so:

Impedance matching 
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching)
is about adapting impedances of source and load. In a 
receiver the antenna acts as source, the 
receiver circuit as load. In the "toy receiver" case about 
the load os just the LC-tank. SO it has a fixed load 
impedance which we cannot modify. In order to satisfy 
the condition $Z_S= Z^*_L$ our "degree of freedom" is
the source (=the antenna)

Comment: and we are going to manipulate it's
impedance in order to obtain the above equality of impedances
(=the "impedance matching"). Assume the is no capacity
C_1. If $Z_S= Z^*_L$ is already holds, we are done. But in 
genral the antenna's inpendance differs from 
fixed complex conjugate impedance of the LC-tank. What to do?
We add to the antenna this coupling capacitor C_1 with 
appropriate capacitance such that now the system 
antenna + capacitor C_1 have impedance which is
equal to the complex conjugate impedance of the LC-tank, ie
that the impedance matching condition is fulfilled now.

Comment: So (if I understand the issue correct now) the trick with the
coupling capacitor here was to add to the antenna this 
capacitor C_1 in 
series WITH ONLY ONE AIM, that now their common impedance
satisfies impedance matching condition with the impedance of
the LC-tank.

Is the idea behind the coupling capacitor correct now?

Comment: No, it's not impedance matching; it's still tuning (in conjunction with the other capacitor) but it allows freedom in shaping the pass-bandwidth in order to optimize signal quality. The antenna will be short (and hence capacitive in nature) and adding more series capacitance does not match its impedance. Forget that idea completely. I would urge you to simulate a voltage source feeding a parallel tuned circuit via a series capacitor and see what happens.

Comment: The series capacitor gives you an extra degree of freedom in both selecting the right frequency and modifying the bandwidth to suit "best" reception. Also take note what I said in comment on the other question; this is a Q and A site. If you want to know how a double capacitor tuned circuit re-shapes the pass frequency and can adjust the Q, then ask a new question.

Comment: Could you then formulate what you precisely mean by 'tuning' of 
a circuit?
Maybe that's the cause of my misunderstanding.

Comment: (Firstly as far as I understand you correctly the reason why my previous conjecture 
that the coupling capacitor helps to archieve the impedance match is wrong here
 is NOT because in general coupling capacitor or coils cannot be used for 
matching, but that's because in THIS special case we have a capacitive antenna
(intuitively a short one), and adding an additional capacitor would 
make it 'more' capacitive. So we would archieve an unwanted opposite effect making
the impedance of this antenna + coupling capacitor deviating much more
from the desired impedance match, right?

Comment: That's the logic here? So in turn applying the 
same logic here if our goal would be to match such capacitive antenna 
to the rest network we should use here a coupling coil here instead of capacitor,
then we would archieve 'impedance matching', right?)

Comment: Back to (hopefully) right explanantion: Maybe now I understand your concern better. So
what you mean is that we consider C_1 NOT as 
an 'auxiliary' component of the antenna to 'artificially'
change it's impedance (see the foregoing comment), but as a part 
of intern 'tuning unit' consisting of C_1, L_1 and C_2 which provide a 'finer'
toolbox to design a receiver network with desired filter's gain magnitude function
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#Electrical_systems), than it
would be possible only with two elements L_1 and C_2?

Comment: So essentially it's just literally like the trivial statement that which more components it's 
possible to construct a functionally more complex network than we could ever build
with fewer components, just 
because the is more freedom for taking choices, nothing more?

Comment: Correct; the extra component provides one more degree of freedom.

Comment: Again to the circuit imaged above: If one is 
not comfortable with the Q factor - like me - can 
the meaning of this coupling capacitor C1 
alternatively concisely be understood in the sense that 
it forms together with L1 and C2 a  
bandpass filter?

Comment: Of course. You solve the transfer function into the standard mathematical form and you get Q or its partial inverse, damping factor, zeta.

Comment: Great, than it was simpler then I thought, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

C1 is usually in the order of 10/20 pico Farad.

It's used in order not to bring DC voltage to the antenna.

C1 must be small in order not to influence the design of the matching network that adapts the antenna's impedance to the output impedance of the RF amplifier/receiver.

---

In some amateur radio transmitters C1 and C2 can be used for tuning the antenna to the transmitter in order to improve the RF performance of the system.

Radio amateurs use C1 and C2 as  two degrees of freedom for fine tuning the antenna on the field.

Comment: The inductor would prevent DC voltage reaching the antenna.

Comment: @Andyaka Only if said inductor had zero resistance.

Comment: @Enrico I'm not sure that it follows that C1 must be small, since you only mention its  function as DC blocking. For DC blocking, any value above a frequency- and load impedance-dependent minimum will do. Smaller values have the benefit of being cheap, and keeping any ESD transient currents they conduct minimal. C1 can also be used for purposes other than DC blocking, such as impedance matching, and then its DC blocking function is incidental, whereas the actual value comes from the circuit's requirements.

Comment: Yes, the preventing DC is as I mentioned one obvious effect by the coupling capacitor, but the main concern behind my question was if that's really all, what the coupling capacitor does in this circuit or are there more reasons involved to place the coupling cap between the antanna and resonant circuit there.

Answer (score 2):

An electrically short antenna has an impedance which is basically a small resistance with a series capacitor.

Thinking of a several metres wire at MW frequencies I'd ballpark a few ohms and a few hundred pF.

This capacity is far from constant and high enough to detune the LC tank.

At the same time the smallish resistance will damp tank Q.

All this is easily cured adding the few tens pF antenna capacitor.

Detuning is now reduced and taken to be rather indipendent from antenna capacitance.

Smaller capacitance also rises the antenna resistance seen by the tank (series to parallel impedances transformation rules).
Tank Q gets higher improving both boosted voltage to detector and selectivity ( well the latter remains poor anyway).

All this proved to be enough for receiving strong local stations when there used to be some.

Comment: Let me try to recapitulate the idea:
So the original problem is that if there is no such
coupling capacitor C1 and we calculate 
the Q factor of the L1-C2-tank (eg with 
this formula
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#RLC_circuits )
Here we should also note that a real coil has **always**
a small resistence component R, so the quoted wiki formula 
can be applied. And this R is small.

Comment: The punchline: And your idea is 
to add the coupling capacitor C1 and then calculate
the Q now of the **new** system consisting of
the  L1-C2-tank is series with cap C1. So now the
Q of the L1-C2-tank not matters any more, only
the new Q of the composition C1, C2, L1 and this
becomes thanks to C1 big, that's the story, right?

Answer (score 1):

C1 would be a capacitor of value small enough to prevent the antenna from damping the Q of the tuned circuit.

In other words, the purpose of C1 would be to improve selectivity.

Comment: Could you give a reference or short sketch how exactly this C1 contributes to the tunning of this circuit. Or in simpler words, why this C1 is really indispensable for the circuit tune here? Cannot it be managed without it, ie only with L1 and C2 alone?

Comment: *Cannot it be managed without it, ie only with L1 and C2 alone?* C1 in VU2NAN's schematic can be omitted if L1/C2 are resonant. L1 is necessary for this circuit to work...it provides a return path for detected audio. For AM broadcast-band radio, it is difficult to erect a long-enough antenna: in that case, you might get better results by replacing C1 with inductance to achieve the series-resonance that VU2NAN mentions.

Comment: ok, so "somehow" adding this parallel coupling capacitor improves the 
selectivity. But how concretely, can it be elaborated precisely in
more strict mathematical framework?