# Antenna coupling via capacitor 2

Tags: rf, antenna, receiver

I would like to clarify following detail I still not
understand so far on the explanation what's the proper purpose
of the coupling capacitor C1 in following receiver
circuit is (found in http://makearadio.com/misc-stuff/regennotes.php )
but there are no explanations what finally the job of this
coupling capacitor is):

[image]

The answers I got to my [original question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/592657/antenna-coupling-via-capacitor) on this problem I asked a week ago, suggest
in unison that this coupling capacitor C1 has an important effect on the
Q factor of the L1-C2-tank, which in responsible for selection of desired frequency.

Since the goal of this L1-C2-tank is to be selective,
it's Q should be relatively big, and seemingly (at least as
far as I understood the answers in the linked discussion)
the Q of the L1-C2-tank depends on this coupling capacitor C1.

I not understand it. Why the tank's Q depends on coupling capacitor?
If we separate the L1-C2-tank from the rest of this circuit
then it's just a parallel LC-circuit:

(note that the LC-tank in the first picture above there is no
resistance R explicitely depicted, that's just for sake
of brevity, a real coil has always a small resistant component
R, which we should take into account if we want to
calculate the Q of this LC-tank.

Now comes the point which confuses me: For a parallel
LC-tank seemingly there is a closed formula for
Q (see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#RLC_circuits).
And the problem is that it seemingly not(!) depends
on the coupling capacitor C1, instead **only** on L1 (+ it's
resistant conponent R menstioned before) and C2? So inly on component which belong to the LC-tank, not external components like the cap C1.

**Problem:** So in summary we deal with two statements:

**(I)** (based on answers from original question  )
"The Q factor of the L1-C2-tank depends explicitely on
capacitor C1 as well"

**(II)** (based on the linked formula from wikipedia)
"The Q of this LC-tank depends only on C2, L1, R

Well, obviously these two statements contradict to each other.
What is the problem here and how to resolve it? Did I quote one of them in
wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

The antenna can be modeled as a resistor in series with a capacitor or inductor depending on its length.

If the antenna resistance is coupled too strongly to L1/C2 it will reduce the Q of the tank.

[Radiation resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_resistance)

Comment: Yes, good note, I updated the image by the model circuit of 
the antenna & added a resistence component to the coil L1
since it's naturally to assume that every coil has 
real resistence; I guess that in the linked page where 
I found this circuit the author was to lazy to add this R
and just assumed that it should be clear to the reader.

Comment: But I think your answer missing slightly the point (I update
the question to emphasise more precisely the problem)
My question was about how to resolve the 
apparent contradiction of the two statements: 
(I) that the Q of the L1-C2-tank **depends** explicitely on
capacity C1, which is not a part of the L-tank
(that's what several answers on the linked question also
suggest) AND (II) the explicite formula from wiki
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#RLC_circuits) for parallel
LCR-circuits (which is of course our L1-C2-tank).

Comment: So seemingly (I) and (II) contradict to each other, since
(I) suggests that Q of L1-C2-tank depends on external components
(ie the capacitor C1), while (II) says no, the tank's Q
depends **only** on components, which belong to the tank, 
namely R, C2 and L1. And that's exactly what confuses me.
Do you see how this seemingly contradiction between
(I) and (II) can be resolved?

Comment: But by the way: could you sketch or give a reference 
for pure formal (ie in mathematical terms) derivation
how the Q of the L1-C2-tank explicitely depends
on coupling capacitor C1. Maybe that will uncover
what is wrong with the formula from
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#RLC_circuits

Comment: @katalaveino neither. Wikipedia gives the correct formula for the Q of the LC tank, but the Q of the LC tank doesn't matter, the Q of the *whole system* matters.

Comment: @hobbs: 
Maybe this Q of the LC tank is less important 
from practical reasons, maybe in most cases it's 
indeed not. But my question was not if it is important 
or not, but which dependencies it does have.

Comment: Mathematically: the function $f(x,y) =x+y$ depends on
$x$ and $y$, but $g(x,y)= x$ only on $x$. Here is
the story similary. The answers from
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/592657/antenna-coupling-via-capacitor
suggest that the Q of the L1-C2-tank **depend* 
on C1, while the wikipedia formula obviously not. That's
my point.

Comment: @katalaveino it doesn't have dependencies, and no they don't imply that, it's just what you incorrectly inferred. Slow down and read what I already wrote.

Comment: @hobbs: 
Sorry, if I misunderstood you. After carefully reading
I still not sure if I understood you correctly.
Let me try to rephrase: so you just wanted to say that formally
the quoted wikipedia formula for the green encircled 
LC-tank is correct, but I just not relevant for *this*
considerations on my initial problem: "What is the job
of coupling capacitor there?" Here the Q of *the* total 
system is the "meaningful" parameter, which reflects 
the contribution of the coupling capacitor? Is that what 
you wanted to say or did I misunderstood you again?

Comment: So in other words: one can formally consider the Q of the LC-tank (which can be indeed calculated by given formula), but it not carries intersting informations to my intial problem? Correct?

Comment: Yes, that exactly. :)