# Notion of Q factor for abstract two-port network

Tags: circuit-analysis, antenna, oscillator, transfer-function

Consider an abstract two-port network/quadripole electrical
network with input voltage \$U_{in}\$, output voltage \$U_{out}\$,
current at input port \$I_{1}\$ and current at output
port  \$I_{2}\$:

[image]

Is there a mathematical criterion
how to decide if it is possible to associate a "meaningful"
notion of the [Q factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor) to this network?

What do I mean by "mathematical criterion?" Well, if we think about a
[(driven) harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Driven_harmonic_oscillators) from classical mechanics, then in mechanical
case one could say that one can associate a Q factor to the mechanical
system if and only if the system can be modeled by differential equation of the form:

$$  \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + 2 a \omega_0 \frac{dx}{dt}+\omega_0^2x= F_{ext}$$

Where \$a, \omega_0 \$ are a priori constants (\$omega_0\$ will be recognized as the frequency of the system) and \$ F_{ext} \$ is the external ("driving") force. Then one sets
\$ Q:= \frac{1}{2a} \$ and interpret physically Q of this oscillating system as
the quotient of the enegy stored and energy lost per cycle.

If we go back to electronics then usually one studies a given network  instead by modeling it as a differential equation, by analyzing the so called [transfer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function) \$H(s)\$
of this network (essentially this is an "equivalent" approach to the
modeling via differential equation; indeed the Laplace transformation mediates between them.)

Indeed, taking a closer look at networks like the high/low/bandpass filters
(which all are elemetary examples for networks, which "have" a well defined Q-factor,) the structure of their transfer functions (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#Physical_interpretatio)) includes rather naturally notion of the Q factor.

**Conjecture/Question 1:**

If we have a general two-port network electrical network as above and assume we know its transfer function, are we able only from careful inspectation of its shape to decide if this network allows a meaningful notion of of a Q factor?
A naive guess: Can it be said that a network allows a meaningful notion of
a Q factor if and only if its denominator is a quadratic polynomial with non-zero linear factor?

**Question 2:**

In light of my first question there arises quite naturally a point which confuses me. Recall how the transfer function of a system with *input signal*
\$ x(t) \$ and *output signal* \$ y(t) \$ was defined as abstract. The transfer function is by definition:

$$    H(s) := \frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}  $$

where \$ X(s) \$ and \$ Y(s) \$ are the Laplace transforms of
\$ x(t) \$ and output \$ y(t) \$. So seemingly, the shape of the denominator
of the transfer function \$ H(s) \$ depends strongly on the input signal.

At first glance that's not really surprising, but on the other hand if my
conjecture in Question 1 is true, then it strongly depends on if the network
allows a meaningful notion of Q on which kind of input signal is given.
In other words it may happen that for one input signal the Q of the network is meaningfullu defined, for another input signal not.

That's strange if we try to think about the the mechanical driven harmonic oscillator I introduced above. The analogy of the input signal there is the external driving force \$F_{ext} \$, but nevertheless there the notion of Q factor exists independing on which external driving force stimulates
the system.

It's strange in the sense that seemingly in the case of electronic network
it depends strongly if there if a notion of Q factor on "what kind of
input signal" passes to the network, while in case of a mechanical system
the notion of Q factor does not depend on the external driving force, the pendant
of the input signal.

Can this confusion/thinking error be coherently resolved?

Comment: \$Q\$, in one definition (there isn't just one such) is a ratio related to the energy lost per *radian*, not full cycle. There are \$2\pi\$ radians in a full cycle. But not all systems are 2nd order. And \$Q\$ has a clear meaning (the way you write it, anyway) only in the case of 2nd order. So that comports with one of your questions, well. Yet I also see the confusion. But it sounds like only a two-way dialog will resolve it. An answer would need to be long, otherwise. (The 'denominator' you mentioned is also called the *characteristic equation*, by the way.)

Comment: @jonk: I probably see your point. So the point you want to emphasize is
that the way I introduced the definition of \$ Q\$ above, 
suggest almost tautologically that my \$ Q\$ can be only defined for
2nd order systems, ie those
having a quadratic poynomial as 
denominator/characteristic equation in the transfer function?
So in light of definition of \$ Q\$ *I gave* the **Question 1**
is rather self-responsive, because this definition of \$ Q\$
was a priori established for 2nd order system?
That's your point, right?

Comment: If yes, then I should admit that unfortunately, I have 
awkwardly expressed my real concern, because originally I wanted to 
find a criterion how to decide if a given system allows a meaningful
notion of \$ Q\$ factor, based on the inspection of structure
of it's transfer function. Of course, if a priori \$ Q\$ as done
 by mine only defined for 2nd order networks, then I'm tautologically 
 just seeking for 2nd order networks,
the dog bites its tail :) Question 1 solves itself. But originally I intended to analyze it for a broader class of networks, not only the of 2nd order.

Comment: In order to express my original concern more precise to avoid such 
misunderstandings, I think the key point is to change 
the definition of \$ Q\$ factor to that one which is admissible
for bigger class of systems, not only the 2nd order systems.
Yes, as you mentioned there are more than one definitions
of \$ Q\$. The three I know are the 
stored energy per cycle definition (yes you right, I missed 
indeed the \$ \pi \$ factor there),the bandwidth 
definition (as the reciprocial) and the damping definition
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#Definition).

Comment: Of course it depends on concrete system/netork and 
context which definition we interested to work with but I think
that in most not too exotic cases these should give coherent
values. Do you think that there is any chance that one 
of these definitions can be used for more general 
networks, ie not only the 2nd order systems (and yes of course we should drop 1st order systems, because notion of \$ Q\$ for these never make 
sense), such that the inspection of the transfer function of
this system may give an answer/ hint if the notion of \$ Q\$
for this network is meaningful defined?

Comment: Or is it finally really ONLY a *pure* 2nd order network business, and 
no such generalization attempts could work?

Comment: Wow! You wrote almost as much as in your question, above. The concept of \$Q\$ has a long history and not everyone agrees upon the same definition. There are good reasons for that fact, too. But I don't want to write as much as you did, trying to pass along what's in my head about it. Suffice it that within the context of electronics, there is a well-defined meaning which applies only to 2nd order. 1st order cannot possibly have such a concept and everything 3rd order and higher cannot be entirely made to support the idea, either, though in specific cases it can be approximated, with caveats.

Comment: A passive 2-terminal pair network has an open-circuit transfer ratio: \$G_s=\frac{N_s}{D_s}=\frac{a_m s^m+a_{m-1} s^{m-1}+\dots+a_1 s+a_0}{b_m s^m+b_{m-1} s^{m-1}+\dots+b_1 s+b_0}\$, where \$a_i\$ and \$b_i\$ are real, positive constants and all \$b_i\$ are non-zero. The problem with passive networks is that all of the poles are on the negative real axis of the s-plane and this greatly limits the ability of RC circuits (for example) to exhibit sharp cutoffs. Which is why attention was rapidly drawn, a century ago, towards active filters, which can arrange the poles and zeros as needed.

Comment: A 2nd order characteristic equation, \$D_s\$, can be normalized by dividing through either by \$b_2\$, causing the leading constant to become 1, or by \$b_0\$, causing the trailing constant to become 1. Either approach is standardized, but the upshot is that there remains two non-one coefficients left to consider. One determines \$\omega_{_0}\$ and the other determines the damping factor, \$\zeta\$, which is a mirror of what has become known as \$Q\$. (They are interchangeable.) A study of the behaviors of 2nd order equations teaches the meaning of these two.

Comment: If you then proceed towards 3rd order and higher, there is no longer just two non-one constants. But now three or more. And they interact. The concepts are a bit different and the study and description of their behaviors expands. The whole field blossoms out. With quadratics, there is a single vertex to consider. But at 3rd order there are two such plus a novel behavior between them, and so on. And it's no longer so easy to pin a clearly defined 2nd order concept to them.

Comment: @jonk: So in summary in strict mathematical framework one 
can only define \$Q\$ only for networks with quadratic
characteristic function. For higher order networks there is
no strict meaning of \$ Q \$, so one can give a "meaning" to \$ Q\$
for higher order networks only in a "spongy" way, like eg try to 
find a 2nd network that "roghly" approximates the behavior of this 
higher order network and then define the \$Q\$ as the well defined \$Q\$ 
of this "approximative" 2nd order network. (at least that's
what came spontaneously into my mind).

Comment: But pure formally \$Q\$ is really
a feature of 2nd order networks only as far as I understood you correctly independently with which definition of \$Q\$ we are working with? In other words one somebody says that "network X has big or small \$Q\$" although network X looks not really like a 2nd order network (or it's quite difficult to check it), then the "rule of thumb" is that one is going approximately (!) regard it as "neary" 2nd order network?

Comment: (the point why I'm asking this is that I often read in several answers statements about nontrivial networks (mostly antenna + receiving systems) like "this has a low or big \$Q\$, or that  \$Q\$ behaves in that way" althogh strictly speaking the network not looks strictly like a 2nd network (or at least that seems not to be obvious). So I assume that in most cases statements like these arise through a rough "estimations" that affected network might nearly behave like a 2nd order network (see eg answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/592657/antenna-coupling-via-capacitor)

Comment: By the way in your last comment you used the word "vertex"
(in quadratic case the system seemingly has only one such "thing",
in higher orders even more; seeminlgy the rule is that n-order network 
has (n-1)-"vertices"?) Stupid question: What do you mean 
in this context by a "vertex"?

Comment: update: the later stupid question about 'vertex' terminology has been settled.
As far as I see it's just another name for an extreme value point of a function. 
Unfortunately, I've never heard of usage of this word in this context and 
the name sounds be a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1):

> So seemingly the shape of the denominator of the transfer function H(s) depends strongly o[n] the input signal.

No. Transfer functions are useful for *linear* circuits, which satisfy *linear* differential equations, at least within the sphere of electrical engineering. So, pretty much by assumption, when the transfer function of a circuit is referred to, it  is assumed that the circuit is linear.

One of the nice properties of linear differential equations is that the transfer function associated with the differential equation does NOT depend upon any particular choice of "input" function.  The input could be a sine wave. The input could be a unit step, the input could be any analytic function, and the transfer function stays the same. That is the *ratio* of the Laplace Transform of the input to the Laplace Transform of the output is not affected by the choice of the input function.

Comment: Yes, I should have added that the networks I consider are always assumed to be linear, thanks. But nevertheless I'm still a bit confused about the statemet you wrote that the transfer function associated with the differential equation does NOT depend upon any particular choice of "input" function. Could you elaborate it (it seems indeed to be to core of my confusion)? I thought that the input function is \$ H(s) := \frac{Y(s)}{X(s)} \$ and since \$X(s) \$ is as

Comment: Laplace trafo of input signal, clearly it depends on it. But then it seems to be logical that then \$H(s)\$ also depends on the imput signal, since by definition it depends on \$X(s)\$. What is the error in my considerations?

Comment: Or is your point that the *ratio* of the both Laplace trafos (=transfer function) itself not depend which signal arives as input. So the output "kills" all special features of the input signal and \$H(s)\$ reflects after this "cancelation" of input by output really only the intrinsic (!) structure of the circuit? That's the point, right?

Comment: Yes. The ratio is a fixed formula even though the Laplace Transform of the input is free to vary. Changing the input will change the output. But, the Laplace transform of the output is always the Laplace transform of the input times the transfer function.

Comment: So essentially what you want to say is that if \$x(t)\$ and \$x'(t)\$ are any two different and arbitrary input signals
(and \$y(t)\$ resp \$y'(t)\$ the associated output) then we have always
\$ \frac{Y(s)}{X(s)} = \frac{Y'(s)}{X'(s)} (=H(s)) \$
(where\$ X(s), Y(s), X'(s), Y'(s) \$ are Laplace trafos of 
\$x(t), y(t), x'(t), y'(t) \$?

Comment: If yes, could you give literature reference where a proof of this independence statement could be found? Of cause that's a strong statement, but seems to be not obvous at first glance.